# hiding from who command and strange carcvncgiw process

Tags: ubuntu

my server have what i think is a suspicious activity, there is bash process that consume more than 30% cpu when i trace it with `lsof -p` it show:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
carcvncgi 39259 root  cwd    DIR    253,1     4096  813203 /var/www/elasticsearch
carcvncgi 39259 root  rtd    DIR    253,1     4096       2 /
carcvncgi 39259 root  txt    REG    253,1   625622 1109822 /usr/bin/carcvncgiw
carcvncgi 39259 root    0u   CHR      1,3      0t0    1029 /dev/null
carcvncgi 39259 root    1u   CHR      1,3      0t0    1029 /dev/null
carcvncgi 39259 root    2u   CHR      1,3      0t0    1029 /dev/null
carcvncgi 39259 root    3u  IPv4 36094970      0t0     UDP *:44932
```

but when i check it with `who` it only show :

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/4    182.253.177.249  09:07    6:45  17.35s  0.28s -bash
root     pts/5    182.253.177.249  09:25   23:57   1.82s  1.75s iftop
root     pts/7    182.253.177.249  09:33    5.00s  0.14s  0.00s w
root     pts/0    103:S.0          22:45    9:29m  0.34s  0.27s /bin/bash
```

three from the top is my ip, the last one i think the provider ip. 
is it possible someone accessing my server and hide it from `who` command ? is there a way to solve this? and what is `carcvncgiw` process as mr.Google doesn't provide clear explanation ?

**UPDATE**

well, I followed here [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and try to deal with the server and 'solve the problem', but the question is remain is it possible to hide from `who` command and what is the `carcvncgiw` process?

note: thanks to the one show me that link, seems i need to purge my server then

**UPDATE 2**

Result of `cat /proc/39259/cmdline`

```
bash
```

Result of `cat /proc/39259/environ`

```
nSHLVL=0OLDPWD=/UPSTART_JOB=lokamedia-elasticTERM=linuxPATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11R6/binPWD=/var/www/elasticsearchNLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.catXFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
```

Result of `ls -lh /usr/bin/carcvncgiw`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 597K Mar 10 00:14 /usr/bin/carcvncgiw
```

thank you

Comment: i update it to clarify the question

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/39259/cmdline` and `cat /proc/39259/environ`, and `ls -lh /usr/bin/carcvncgiw`?

Comment: update the question again, will it cause any harm if I remove the file?

Comment: As a side note `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/39259/environ` should make the environment more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `who` command prints information about users who are logged on, the `utmp` file is the primary source for that information.

According to the manual [**`man 5 wtmp`**](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp)  the init process clears the entries for processes started at system boot time, so the `carcvncgi` process might have been started at system boot by init (or the systemd/upstart replacements of init) and can actually be part of your normal process list.

Regardless `/var/run/utmp` is only updated for actual [`login`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/login) events and not for each and every process that gets started.

A program doesn't have to anything special to "hide" from the `who` command, it is almost the reverse, it takes a specific action to be listed in the first place.

About the validity of that `carcvncgi`  process: no idea really.